# Не получается привязать текст и кнопки к ViewModel

Tags: c#, uwp, binding

Решил воспользоваться новым элементом NavigationView, для построения меню. Всё бы ничего, но не совсем понимаю как привязать переопределенную область заголовка. Имеется следующая разметка:

```
    <NavigationView.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:MainViewModel">
            <Grid Margin="24,10,0,0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock
                    Margin="0,0,0,10"
                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                    FontSize="28"
                    Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"
                    Text="{x:Bind Title, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <CommandBar
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                    DefaultLabelPosition="Right">
                    <AppBarButton
                        Click="{x:Bind FeedBack}"
                        Icon="Edit"
                        Label="Сообщение" />
                </CommandBar>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </NavigationView.HeaderTemplate>
```

Требуется привязать TextBlock к заголовку, который бы менялся при переходе на различные страницы, а так же кнопку CommandBar'а, показывающую сообщение при нажатии.
В code behind объявляется ViewModel:

```
public MainPage()
        {
            ViewModel = new MainViewModel();
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

Собственно сам ViewModel:

```
public MainViewModel()
        {
            Title = "Main page";
        }

        private string title;
        public string Title
        {
            get { return title; }
            set
            {
                title = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public async void FeedBack()
        {
            await (new MessageDialog("Home!")).ShowAsync();
        }

        public async void NavView_SelectionChanged(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationView sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationViewSelectionChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationViewItem item = args.SelectedItem as Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationViewItem;

            switch (item.Tag)
            {
                case "home":
                    await (new MessageDialog("First")).ShowAsync();
                    Title = "First page";
                    break;

                case "schedule":
                    await (new MessageDialog("Second Page")).ShowAsync();
                    Title = "Second page";
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

После перехода на различные страницы, заголовок остаётся пустым, а при нажатии на кнопку сообщения, вылетает исключение. Каким образом можно привязаться к ViewModel в данном случае, и возможно ли обойтись без code behind?

Comment: Почему бы вам не переопределять эти параметры прямо в коде? Даете имя вашему NavigationView. И прям в коде менять Title. Например так, NavView.Header = "Home";
И тоже самое проделать с AppBarButton.

Comment: @ЖуэльИтуа это сделать можно, только проблема в том, что ViewModel будет знать непосредственно о View. Хотелось бы решить проблему "элегантно".

Comment: Я не знаю как это сделать, но судя по предоставленному xaml коду а вас есть ссылка на тип объекта DataType, но не указан источник данных. То есть приложение не знает откуда брать данный. Попробуйте найти способ указать источник данных или указывайте ссылку на свойства и методы объекта ViewModel ( Например, Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.Title}")